# How to add the whole row? I tried everything but no luck

Tags: php, sql

```
$sql_main = "SELECT artistcd.cdID,artistcd.cdTitle,artistcd.cdPrice, sum(artistCD.cdPrice * sdetails.qty) AS TotalSales, 
    (SELECT SUM(TotalSales)) FROM artistcd NATURAL JOIN sdetails WHERE artistID = $artistID";
```

The supposedly output is like this:
[image]

Comment: Try CROSS JOIN instead of NATURAL JOIN.

Answer (score 0):

Combining what is possible in a database and what you might want to achieve, I come out with the below. Your DB must support the WITH clause, though.

```
WITH
detail AS (
SELECT 
  artistcd.cdID
, artistcd.cdTitle
, artistcd.cdPrice
, sum(artistcd.cdPrice * sdetails.qty) AS TotalSales
FROM artistcd 
NATURAL
JOIN sdetails
WHERE artistID = $ARTISTID
)
SELECT
  *
FROM detail
UNION ALL
SELECT
  999999999999      AS cdID
, 'All Titles'      AS cdTitle
, CAST(NULL AS INT) AS cdPrice
, SUM(TotalSales)   AS TotalSales
FROM detail
ORDER BY 1
;
```